# Unable to write map for the function

Tags: scala, map-function

I have a data like this:

```
val timeArr = Array("09:00:00|09:30:00", "10:00:00|11:00:00", "12:00:00|15:00:00","10:00:01|13:23:55")
```

I would like my output in the following manner

```
(‘09:00:00’, ‘S’)
(‘09:30:00’, ‘E’)
(‘10:00:00’, ‘S’)
(‘10:00:01’, ‘S’)
(‘11:00:00’, ‘E’)
(‘12:00:00’, ‘S’)
(‘13:23:55’, ‘E’)
(‘15:00:00’, ‘E’)
```

having `S` for start time and `E` for end time.

I tried various ways using `map`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Would "How to split strings in an array and map the results?" be a better title for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a "[code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)" challenge, I wanted to see how short I could make it.

```
timeArr.flatMap(x => Array((x take 8, 'S'), (x drop 9, 'E')))
```

Comment: Nice catch! Taking into account that the format of time is always hh:MM:ss ;)

Comment: Short and elegant!

Comment: Nice solution i never thought of it.

Answer (score 4):

Building off of @mfirry answer I think this gives what you want.

The `split("|")` yields an `Array[Array[String]]` which is a little clumsy to work with. Using `flatMap` and  `case Array(a, b, _*)` makes working with the inner arrays easier to get the desired output. Lastly, you sort on the first element (time) of the tuple.

```
scala> timeArr.map(_.split("\\|")).flatMap { case Array(a, b, _*) => Array((a, 'S'), (b, 'E'))}.sortBy(t => t._1)

res150: Array[(String, Char)] = 
 Array(
   (09:00:00,S),
   (09:30:00,E),
   (10:00:00,S),
   (10:00:01,S),
   (11:00:00,E),
   (12:00:00,S),
   (13:23:55,E),
   (15:00:00,E)
 )
```

Comment: It's true I miss to sort the results!! Nice @Brian

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
for {
  a <- timeArr.map(_.split("\\|"))
  b <- a.zipWithIndex.map{ case (e, i) => if(i == 0) { (e,'S') } else (e, 'E') }
} yield b
```

or a funny one-liner:

`timeArr.map(_.split("\\|")).flatMap { case Array(a, b, _*) => Array((a, 'S'), (b, 'E')) }`

Comment: This doesn't sort the result by time, but the example in the question appears to be sorted by time.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a map to create tuples (start, end) and then what you miss is to create a flatMap.

Try something like this:

```
val result = timeArr.map(_.split("\\|"))
  .flatMap(t => (t(0), 'S') :: (t(1), 'E') :: Nil)
```

Some explanation:

```
map(_.split("\\|")
```

This split the string into an Array of String, so each element of the original collection now has an Array of String.

So... now you have an Array of Arrays... but you need a simple Array. For this type of problem is when you need to use flatMap:

```
flatMap(t => (t(0), 'S') :: (t(1), 'E') :: Nil)
```

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation but flat map was flattening the whole result. I was not getting the tuples as expected.

Comment: timeArr.map(_.split("\\|")).flatMap { case Array(a, b, _*) => Array((a, 'S'), (b, 'E')) }  did the trick

Comment: Sorry I created a flatMap of String instead of a tuple, let me edit.